# UILongPressGestureRecognizer getting fired twice

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

UILongPressGestureRecognizer is getting fired twice when user long presses on a map for over 2-4 seconds.  How can I ensure it will only be fired once?

```
func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {

    println("long pressed on map")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    if activePlace == -1 {

        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()



    } else {

        var uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "action:")
        uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
        myMap.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)

    }        
}

func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {

    println("long pressed on map")
    var touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.myMap)
    var newCoordinate = myMap.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.myMap)

    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
    //annotation.title = "New Place"
    myMap.addAnnotation(annotation)

    var loc = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinate.latitude, longitude: newCoordinate.longitude)

}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have to check the gesture recognizer´s `state` for the begin of the gesture:

```
func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Long-press gestures are continuous. The gesture begins (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) when the number of allowable fingers (numberOfTouchesRequired) have been pressed for the specified period (minimumPressDuration) and the touches do not move beyond the allowable range of movement (allowableMovement). The gesture recognizer transitions to the Change state whenever a finger moves, and it ends (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) when any of the fingers are lifted.

try something like this:

```
let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target : self,
 action : #selector(someFunc(gestureRecognizer:)))


func someFunc(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
//do something
}
```