# UILongPressGestureRecognizer sending action twice

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, presentviewcontroller, long-press

**My Long Press Gesture Recognizer is causing its action event to be executed *twice***?

I was trying to figure out a `Warning: Attempt to present VC2 on VC1 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

By using some println() tests, I found that my VC2 is being presented twice.

**My VC2 presentation method:**

P1long:UILongPressGestureRecognizer located on VC1's MainView

[image: VC1.P1long connections]

When long press done on `P1` of VC1

```
@IBAction func PresentPlayerInfo(sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
    var loc = sender.locationInView(self.view)
    var segueSwitch = 0

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.P1.frame, lock)) 
        { tappedView = self.P1; segueSwitch = 1 }
    else if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.ReDeal.frame, lock)) 
        { tappedView = self.ReDeal; segueSwitch = 2 }

    if segueSwitch == 1
        { performSegueWithIdentifier("PlayersTable", sender: self)
        println("PlayersTable") }

    else if segueSwitch == 2 
        { self.viewDidLoad() }
}
```

---

Console output:

`PlayersTable
 PlayersTable
 Warning: Attempt to present <iPro_Poker_HH_swift.VC2: 0x14555470> on <iPro_Poker_HH_swift.VC1: 0x153a2600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Why is my LongPress acting twice.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685851/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-getting-fired-twice?rq=1) and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should handle long press gesture recognizer's state. UILongPressGestureRecognizer's action invokes on it's state changes. So you are receiving it first time when state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan and second time when its UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded.

You need something like:

```
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    //your action
}
```

Comment: Are all the GestureRecognizers like that too?